# WordPress Twenty Fourteen theme 3rd level rollover goes off screen on small monitors

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a client who wants 3 levels of navigation in the primary-navigation. (Not recommending this for accessibility reasons.) The problem is that the third level sits to the right of the second level and goes off the screen when the screen is about 1000 pixels wide or less. To mitigate this, the client would like the third menu to sit on the left of the 2nd (dropdown) menu. I'm having some difficulty figuring out which layer controls the position of this menu.

Clues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, my brain wouldn't let it go, and I realized I needed to search for :hover. Here is the correct layer in the parent theme.
    .primary-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
    .primary-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul 
    {
        left: -150px;
    }

You can see this effect on http://lincolnmontana.com/. I left it overlapping the 2nd level menu a bit.